# Is it possible to restrict php script access to the whole system and environment?

Tags: php

For example, avoiding a php script accessing $_SESSION, the `sleep`or exit function, includes and of course changing any crucially important server configuration via php (such as a timeout) and make the range of that script something purely *local* to the script where its permissions begin right when the script starts and end at its bottom.

Comment: Look into php sanboxes. This allows you to run any script in a controlled enviroment.

Comment: 3v4l.org for example uses VMs.